# Some questions about System.Threading.Timer and Parallel

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I would like to start some of my functions every x second. But I dont want to wait for any function until its done before Im starting the function again. Let say I set the timer to 5 sec and I start `functionX()` and after 5 sec `functionX()` is not done => I want to start `functionX()` again in a new thread. I also want that a group of functions are starting at the same time.

Thats why I thought I have to use `System.Threading.Timer` and `Parallel` Lets write a short example, I thought this is how it should be:

```
class Program
    {
        private static System.Threading.Timer timer;
        private static int interval = 2000;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("go");
            Run();
            Console.WriteLine("end");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        private static void Run()
        {
            timer = new System.Threading.Timer(TimerCallback, null, 0, interval);
        }

        private static void TimerCallback(Object o) {
            Parallel.Invoke(() => FunctionA(), () => FunctionB(), () => FunctionC());
        }

        private static void FunctionA()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("A");
        }

        private static void FunctionB()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("B");
        }

        private static void FunctionC()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("C");
        }
    }
```

Is this alright? Any suggestions? Even if this code is somehow wrong: I would like to ask another question about my output - if I start this Code I get something like this as output:

```
go
end
A
B
C
C
A
B
C
A
B
C
B
A
```

Uhm. The first output `go` is fine, but why is the second one `end` , why not `A`,`B`,`C`? And is that normal, that the output A,B,C is somehow after the first output random?

The next problem what I dont understand: if I remove the line                 `Console.ReadKey();` I cannot see any output.

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("go");
            Run();
            Console.WriteLine("end");
        }
```

I mean the consol is starting but after some millisec its closed and its not opening again. But it should be appear because Im calling A,B,C again and again, so a new consol should appear again and again. Any ideas? Thank you

Comment: New threads started asynchronously as you are doing don't stop the current thread from continuing on, and even exiting, which stops all child threads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main method returns immediately after the timer was created. That's why the `end` is written so early. All the rest of your code is executed in other threads.

You timer methods sends three jobs to .NETs Parallel extensions, which also execute the jobs in background threads. That's why you do not see orderd output like ABC, but ACB, BCA CBA and so on.

So you have a main thread, a timer background thread and up to three worker threads for the output (depending on your CPU).

The `Console.ReadKey()` makes the mail thread to wait for keyboard input. During this time, the other threads can process their jobs. When you remove the `ReadKey` call, your programm immediately ends after it wrote `end` and does not wait for the other threads to finish.

Change your code not only to write start, end and ABC, but also add `Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadID` to the output. Then you can see which thread runs which method.

Answer (score 1):

Parallel (and other similar frameworks) doesn't guarantee the execution order of the started tasks (threads). If you want to guarantee that the execution order is ''A, B, C'' you could put them into a function, and execute that in thread.

On the other way, exiting from ''Main'' interrupts the running threads. A typical service has to loop indefinitely until it reaches the exit condition (user press a ESC, receives a signal, so on).

As your threads are running within a single application, they will never open a new console window for their output.